# opencv 2.2 xcode4 ios4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv, xcode4, ios4

To build and install OpenCv2.2 I followed the instructions here: http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/02/building-opencv-for-iphone-in-one-click/ , http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/01/using-opencv-in-objective-c-code/
The build script of OpenCv seems to work fine.. but after adding the libraries and headers to my XCode4 project I still have the same troubles:

```
/opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp
opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2075:15: error: map: No such file or directory

opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2076:18: error: string: No such file or directory

opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2077:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory

opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2084: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'public'

opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2106: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CvMLData'

opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2186: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'cv'
```

I already have tried to add the `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` to my `***-Prefix.pch` file and added  linker flags: `-lstdc++ -lz`, but still these errors.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

download the pre compiled static library for opencv 2.0 
http://computer-vision-talks.com/download/opencv_build_ios_4771.zip

and headers from https://github.com/niw/iphone_opencv_test 
worked for me :)

Comment: well, the old version of opencv is also running in my project.. i am able to include the #include "opencv/cv.h" header file.. but not the new version and opencv 2.2 changed a lot..